# VBA loop omitted while executing through F5, but executes on step by step execution using F8

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have some values (derived out of a formula) in a particular row in an excel sheet. I am trying to drag them down till a certain number of rows using `.FillDown` method of `Range` looping through all the columns.

```
Sub RawDataPreparation()

    Dim v As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Metadata").Range("B10")

    Dim ColName() As String
    ReDim ColName(c)

    Dim strFormulas() As Variant
    ReDim strFormulas(c)

    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    For i = 0 To c - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        ColName(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Metadata").Range("C" & i + 10) 'copy the value corresponding to column C10:C18 in Metadata sheet to the array
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(1, lastColumn + 1 + i).Value = ColName(i)
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For j = 0 To c - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        strFormulas(j) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Metadata").Range("D" & j + 10) 'copy the formulas corresponding to column D10:D18 in Metadata sheet to the array
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
            .Cells(2, lastColumn + 1 + j).Formula = strFormulas(j)
        End With
    Next j

    'Code to drag down the formula till last row.
    For k = 0 To c - 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(2, lastColumn + 1 + k), Cells(LastRow, lastColumn + 1 + k)).FillDown
    Next k

End Sub
```

When I execute using F8 (step by step) the last loop (to drag the formula till last row) is being executed and giving intended result. But upon executing the entire `Sub RawDataPreparation` using F5, the last loop is getting omitted.

I am not able to understand this behavior. Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: comment out `On Error Resume Next` and run it again to see if there are any errors. It is a bad practice to silence any errors. Starting from this line to the end of the sub any error are silenced and you will never notice them. At least use `On Error Goto 0` somewhere to stop silencing errors.

Comment: Please provide the input necessary to reproduce this issue. Otherwise it's really difficult to help. More: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Peh, due to the 'On error resume next ' it was not allowing the error to pop up. It was giving an error 1004 for the last loop which was not executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify references to `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows`, etc unless you **KNOW** that your `ActiveSheet` is the sheet being referred to.

So change your last statement to

```
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(2, lastColumn + 1 + k), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Cells(LastRow, lastColumn + 1 + k)).FillDown
```

Or, to make it a bit easier to read:

```
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
       .Range(.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1 + k), .Cells(LastRow, lastColumn + 1 + k)).FillDown
   End With
```

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, that resolved my issue with the Error 1004. :)

Comment: Sorry @YowE3K. I didn't see your post until after I uploaded my response. Exactly the point you made to me the other day :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your code work the last loop should define the range somewhat like this:-

```
Dim k As Long

For k = 0 To C - 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
        .Range(.Cells(2, lastColumn + 1 + k), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1 + k)).FillDown
    End With
Next k
```

Observe the period before the `Cells` defining the range. This period makes the references refer to the "Raw Data" sheet, whereas in your code, in the absence of any spacification, they refer to the ActiveSheet. So you get a different result not depending upon how you trigger the code but which is the active sheet at the time.

Anyway, to prove my point I had to almost rewrite your code. I continued to finish the job, and here it is.

```
Sub RawDataPreparation()
    ' 24 Mar 2017

    Dim WsMetadata As Worksheet
    Dim WsRawData As Worksheet
    Dim firstMetaRow As Long, TransferRow As Long
    Dim nextCol As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    firstMetaRow = 10    ' set this value here instead of in the code
    Set WsMetadata = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Metadata")
    TransferRow = CLng(Val(WsMetadata.Range("B10").Value)) - 1
    ' B10 can't have a value < 1. In your example it should be 9
    If TransferRow < 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set WsRawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data")
    With WsRawData
        nextCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    End With

    ' transpose columns C and D of WsMetaData to rows 1 and 2 in WsRawData
    For R = firstMetaRow To (firstMetaRow + TransferRow)
        With WsMetadata
            .Cells(R, "C").Copy Destination:=WsRawData.Cells(1, (nextCol + R - firstMetaRow))
            .Cells(R, "D").Copy Destination:=WsRawData.Cells(2, (nextCol + R - firstMetaRow))
        End With
    Next R

    With WsRawData
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(2, nextCol), .Cells(lastRow, nextCol + TransferRow)).FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

It works, but unfortunately it may not do the job you envisioned. The formulas you copy from the Metadata contain references to that sheet which can't be translated 1:1 once the range is transposed. You may have to settle for pasting values or translate the formulas before filling them down.